# Managing client passwords

Tags: password-management

I am just starting up a small website development business and one of the issues I am having is remembering passwords and account information for clients hosting, cpanel, ftp accounts etc.

I was wondering what is the most suitable system / industry standard for controlling such information?

Pretty marginal on the close there... I read the FAQ and I felt list this could be a common issue for webmasters, its defiantly not a coding questions so stackoverflow is out of the question and its not a broad question its focused on one particular aspect of being a webmaster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to [manage client passwords without going crazy](http://authoritylabs.com/blog/managing-client-passwords/).

What you are looking for is a password manager. You have a few options

- [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/)
- [KeePass](http://keepass.info/)
- [RoboForm](http://www.roboform.com/)
- [PassPack](https://www.passpack.com/online/)
- A home-brewed solution. Like keeping the accounts in some document

But remember, since these are your clients passwords and account information, security should be a priority (for the sake of your customer and your business).

Edit:
I linked to each now that I'm over 10 rep (couldn't before).

Also, you may find that some services offer special features for those who are storing customer accounts vs just a bunch of personal passwords

Comment: okay perfect!!! yup information security is a priority so will check out the options you have.. thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: LastPass is the one I am liking the most just trying them all out now.. looks like we have a winner.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep LastPass in mind. It is mentioned quite frequently, but I've never committed to using it.